# Deploy a serverless AWS provider with different yml file name

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

I have two differents serverless configurations. One is the STAGE configuration and another is the SHARED configuration.

Each stage must have the same shared resources.

So I have two YML files:

- serverless.yml
- serverless.shared.yml

How can I call the node serverless command to deploy the "serverless.shared.yml" configuration file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible now by using the following command:

```
sls deploy --config serverless.shared.yml
```

Only the `--config` option works. For some reason, the shorter version, `-c`, which is supposed to do exactly the same according to the documentation, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How to run this sls command? I can see this file inside node_modules, but I never used before.

Comment: @JáderCarvalhodeMedeiros just type it in your terminal, as you would do with you usual serverless.yml file. If you still don't know how to proceed, I recommend you the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUTGk64jppM&list=PLzvRQMJ9HDiT5b4OsmIBiMbsPjfp4kfg3&index=1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for now it's not possible.

But I've found the [issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4485) in the serverless github repo.
You can track the state of the following issue.